# Kendo numberictextbox border

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
  .Name("Qty")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 80px;height: 15px;font-size: 11px;" })
  .Format("#")
  .Value(1)
  .Spinners(false))
```

In JavaScript, I have this:

```
var widget = $("#Qty").kendoNumericTextBox().data("kendoNumericTextBox");
widget.wrapper.css("border", "1px solid red").find(".k-select").hide();
```

How can I fix this so that the red border appears on the bottom of the box?

[image]

Comment: You need to use your browser developer tools in order to see - why is border not shown? Is it hidden or is this CSS rule overriden? If it is overriden, then by which rule?

Answer (score 0):

Your height is too small for this font-size (height: 15px). Perhaps you should consider increasing it or removing it all together.

Also when obtaining reference of the widget in JavaScript, you should use:

```
var widget = $("#Qty").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

instead of:

```
var widget = $("#Qty").kendoNumericTextBox().data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

Otherwise you will create second instance of the widget, when setting MVC wrappers Kendo will initialize the widget automatically, no need to initialize it explicitly.

> Duplicate Kendo UI Widget Initialization
>   When using a Kendo UI server-side wrapper (as the server-side wrappers are automatically initialized) or when a widget is being created in an event handler executed multiple times, it is possible to initialize a widget on the same DOM element more than once. In such a scenario, do not try to recreate a widget instance when the goal is to get the instance object.
>
> A common mistake is to recreate a widget instance when the goal is only to get the instance object. Duplicate initialization is not supported and results in unexpected side effects.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/jquery-initialization#duplicate-kendo-ui-widget-initialization